# Disable zoom on Wacom Bamboo Pad (CTH-300)

Tags: xubuntu, touchpad, tablet, wacom, bamboo

I recently managed to get my Wacom Bamboo Pad (CTH-300) working with Xubuntu.
When using it in Windows I have the zoom option disabled, because it is too sensitive if you ask me (often it will start zooming in/out when I just want to scroll).

I'm experiencing the same "unwanted" behavior on Xubuntu, so I wish to disable the zoom functionality.
Unfortunately I do not have a clue on how I can do this. Can someone tell me?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are facing this problem on firefox (xubuntu) so this is help for you further.

> 1.Run Firefox.
>
> 2.In the address bar, type about:config and hit Enter on your key. You will be shown a warning message and asked if you want to continue.
>   Click I’ll be careful, I promise.
>
> 3.You need to type in mousewheel.with_meta.action in search bar
>
> 4.Finally, double-click mousewheel.with_meta.action from Preference Name, enter 0 (the number zero) in the dialog box that opens, and
>   click OK:
>
> 5.Done! If you have some websites zoomed in, be sure to clear browsing history to remove the zoom… and then never worry about this annoying
>   as hell feature again.

OR

```
$xinput | grep -i touchpad
```

check if you touch pad is visible & go forward.

in the file 
/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf    or /etc/X11/Xsession.d/50-synaptics.conf

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "touchpad"
    Driver "synaptics"
    MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        Option "TapButton1" "1"
        Option "TapButton2" "2"
        Option "TapButton3" "3"
        Option "VertEdgeScroll" "on"
        Option "VertTwoFingerScroll" "on"
        Option "HorizEdgeScroll" "on"
        Option "HorizTwoFingerScroll" "on"
        Option "CircularScrolling" "on"
        Option "CircScrollTrigger" "2"
        Option "EmulateTwoFingerMinZ" "40"
        Option "EmulateTwoFingerMinW" "8"
        Option "CoastingSpeed" "0"
        Option "FingerLow" "35"
        Option "FingerHigh" "40"
        ... EndSection
```

edit according to your need.

**Caution**

```
note if you dont have this folder/file create it and add the following file in it.
```

[reference](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1361)

Comment: I do not use Firefox, I use Chrome. Also, I don't think that this problem is limited to a web browser.

Comment: Everytime you write a quetion give samples errors 2 or 3.

Comment: "errors 2 or 3"?
Note that I do not have a synaptics touchpad, but a Wacom Bamboo Pad. I tried to modify the .conf file, but without success. Which Option should I disable?

Comment: ** Option "VertEdgeScroll" "on"  **  you can also use it as a hint and try some of your tricks ,because i am not using bamboo touchpad.

Comment: According to http://linux.die.net/man/4/wacom the only zoom related Option seems to be ZoomDistance. I tried to change that in the past, but that did not help.